# Need help creating a HTML widget. Does anyone know why this oval is enlarged?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a HTML widget for my phone. I need the blue oval to be much smaller and in the upper left corner of my screen. I've (unsuccessfully) combined the code for this oval with code for another clock widget, as I can only run one widget on my phone at a time. I believe it's the clock widget's formatting is affecting the oval, but I'm not exactly sure what all the code means or how I would fix it.

The lines of code that refer to "oval" are the lines that I've added.

Here's a picture to better explain what I'm trying to do:

[image]
(I want the blue oval to snugly fit around the time.)

If you need any more information, I'd be happy to provide what I can! Thanks

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>EW.WdgtPack.6_SB2 by Evelyn (@ev_ynw)</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/lang.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a style="padding-top: 5px; " id="oval"></a>
  </body>

  <body onload="init()">

    <div id="R" style="display:none;"></div>

    <div id="weekday"></div>
    <div id="weekday1"></div>

    <div id="Time">
      -<a id="hour"></a>:<a id="minute"></a><a id="ampm"></a> / <a id="month"></a> <a id="date"></a>-
    </div>

    <script>
      (function() {
        'use strict';
        if (window.innerWidth === 320) {
          document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.85, maximum-scale=0.85, user-scalable=0');
        } else if (window.innerWidth === 414) {
          document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.104, maximum-scale=1.104, user-scalable=0');
        } else if (window.innerWidth === 425) {
          document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.133, maximum-scale=1.133, user-scalable=0');
        } else if (window.innerWidth === 432) {
          document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.152, maximum-scale=1.152, user-scalable=0');
        }
      }());

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: future;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  letter-spacing: 1;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: future;
  src: url(Stuff/Future.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ber;
  src: url(Stuff/Bernier.otf);
}

#R {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 146.74px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#weekday1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.36px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 60;
  font-size: 142.5px;
  font-family: ber;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 25%, 0 53%);
}

#weekday {
  position: absolute;
  top: 53.36px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 50;
  font-size: 142.5px;
  font-family: ber;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70%, 100% 42%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

#Time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 126.73px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 375px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 70;
  font-size: 11.25px;
  color: #E34252;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
}

#oval {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, #54C7FC, #0076FF);
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 43px;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

Comment: Did you try simply reducing the width and height of the oval's css? `#oval { ... width: 115px; height: 43px; ... }`

Comment: I made you a snippet. You had TWO body tags and called some unknown script called INIT on one of them. Please change the snippet to include only relevant code in a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I barely know what I'm doing, and the code isn't originally mine. I was just told that the people on stackoverflow might be able to help out.      I have tried editing the height and width, and it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the explicit `width` and `height` of the oval element.
Let the content determine its size:

```css
.oval {

  /*
  REMOVED for demonstration purposes
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  */
  
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, #54C7FC, #0076FF);
  z-index: -10;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  
  
  /* ADDED for demonstration purposes */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<a class="oval">Content</a>
<a class="oval">Longer Content</a>
<a class="oval">Multi-line<br>Content</a>
```

---

### Edit

In other words, I'm not sure why the clock and oval need to be separate elements.
Example below:

```css
#Time {

  /*
  DISABLED for this demo
  position: absolute;
  top: 126.73px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 70;
  */
  
  /*width: 375px; REMOVED THIS */
  
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #E34252;
  border-radius: 32em;
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, #54C7FC, #0076FF);
  color: black;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="Time">
  <span id="hour">2</span>:
  <span id="minute">28</span>
  <span id="ampm">pm</span> /
  <span id="month">March</span>
  <span id="date">23</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea but the problem is there is no content. It is just simply supposed to be a blank oval that sits behind my clock. That's why I originally had the height and width set.

Comment: Ok, I see. Your code doesn't seem to accurately reflect that issue. Is `<div id="Time">` the clock element that is supposed to lay over the oval?

Comment: Yeah I see why thats a little confusing. Let me try to explain from the start. I found a free widget online that displays both time and the date. If you look at the picture above, thats the big widget in the top middle of the screen. The code for that widget is much more advanced than anything I've worked with, and any references to time or date belong to it. I then thought it would be cool to add a basic oval behind the stock iOS clock which is in the upper left corner of the picture. The only lines of code I added to the original widget are the ones that reference "oval".

Comment: <body>
    <a style="padding-top: 5px; " id="oval"></a>
    </body>

Comment: #oval {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, #54C7FC, #0076FF);
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 43px;
  z-index: -10;
}

Comment: Sorry for my horrendous formatting, this is my first time using this website and I'm still trying to figure everything out. The two comments above are the only two things I've added to the original widget.

Comment: You can change the `width` and `height` as @csmckelvey originally commented. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/4fov22w7/1/).